# How to plot curves (the number may be varied) for different colors in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I hope someone can help me to solve the following coding problem.

When I do optimization, which is a least squared minimization: `Sum(y(modeled)-y(True))^2`, I want to plot graphs after each iteration when doing the optimization. For the graphs, I want to plot in a single figure as follow:

1. the TRUE y (blue line)
2. MODELED y calculated in each iteration. MODELED y obtained in each iteration should be of different colors, do not use the same color

However, there is a difficulty that I do not know the number of iteration the program can execute, it may be a few iterations for simple function, or huge iterations for complicated function.

How to write the corresponding codes in matlab?

I have searched that I can use `PlotFcn` to help me plot graphs. But I do not think helpful since the graphs default do not plot graphs what I want, which force me to write codes myself. I use `OutputFcn` instead. If it is possible to do the same task using `PlotFcn`, please let me know. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you just want to plot multiple curves on the same figure, just use `hold on`. You can also hold multiple figure. `figure(1), plot(...), hold on;` and then a second figure `figure(2), plot(...), hold on;`. Then you can plot on figure 1 again using the first command. Colors will automatically rotate on held figures.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
plot(trueY,'b');
hold on;
while(~finished)
   %....generate a modeledY
    plot(modeledY, 'Color', random(1,3));
   %....determine if finished 
end
```

This doesn't let you control the color that you'll have, but it lets you do as many as you want.  If you want to control the color, check [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/105104-how-to-do-plotting-with-different-colors-in-same-figure) out.

Comment: I do not need to control the color, what I want is that the color to be different when I plot different curves without repeating.